# How do I specify packet data in Net::RawIP?

Tags: perl, tcp, network-programming, ip

According to the cpan documentation I can create a raw packet with the following code:

```
  use Net::RawIP;
  $n = Net::RawIP->new({
                        ip  => {
                                saddr => 'my.target.lan',
                                daddr => 'my.target.lan',
                               },
                       });
                        tcp => {
                                source => 139,
                                dest   => 139,
                                psh    => 1,
                                syn    => 1,
                               },
                       });
  $n->send;
```

But where do I declare the data the packet contains?

Can I send the packet with another module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are sending a `tcp` packet you need as the documentations says to specify:

```
$n = Net::RawIP->new({
  ip  => {
   saddr => 'my.target.lan',
   daddr => 'my.target.lan',
  },
  tcp => {
   source => 139,
   dest   => 139,
   psh    => 1,
   syn    => 1,
   data   => $your_data
  },
 });
```